# How do I solve the issue while entering data into tables in a website using VBA in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automation, data-entry

I am writing a VBA code to enter students' marks automatically from an excel sheet into a website. I am able to log in, navigate to the required page. But when I am trying to enter the marks using VBA into the table, I get the following error.
Run-time error '91':
"Object variable or with block variable not set"

at the line:

```
doc.getElementById(celID).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Marks").Range(ceL).Value
```

where celID is obtained using: celID = "marks-" & regno & "-" & qno and I get it as "marks-171FA04001-1"

The HTML code for the page is:

[Web page HTML code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pt1mIqTFuDAVz8RyCqpTeDtB0Rb0Lu7dANsvetkiiV0/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to verify the table's cell name and enter the marks because the name of the cell changes for different students like marks-rollno-questiono. So I need my code to verify if I am entering the marks for the respective student and for the respective question number. Please help me. I am using a for loop for entering the marks of all the questions of all the students.

[VBA Code for Data Entry](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wuIozFicaeyvJz84PAtQyT2zRk-q08XxGFToJrMwtVU/edit?usp=sharing)

Screenshot of the table:

![3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIBL7.png

Comment: Can you edit the whole HTML snippet of the table and your whole VBA code to your post please? Looks like you do the right things but I can't see why the error occours, with the code you have posted. Occours the error allways with the first `celID`? All `regno` are known and allways the same for every pupil and not only random parts of the web page?

Comment: For your first question. I presume you are asking me to post all the HTML code from the web page and the whole VBA code.

for the second question: It is occurring at first instance.

For the third question: For a section to which a faculty goes, the regno are known. But they change depending upon the section/branch with which the faculty deals.

Comment: I have modified the post.

Comment: The linked code is very helpful. So helpful that I can see you're new to web scraping. Right? Since it's about a school platform and entering grades, I assume you are a teacher or work for a school in IT or both. The VBA code takes care of logging into the page and selecting the correct entries in drop-down lists before the problematic part. If you want, I can set up an email address where you can send me your Excel file and the HTML code of the two pages mentioned. I would then take a look at the whole project. I'm a big fan of education and if it helps, I'm happy to offer further help here.

Comment: You are right, I am new to VBA. Everything works except the part mentioned. I have tried with a regular look up

Comment: You are right, I am new to web scraping and VBA as well. I am a faculty in a university. I am doing it as I found it interesting to do web scraping so that my colleagues and I can benefit in the future from reduced time for entering the marks.

Everything works except the part mentioned. I have tried with a regular look up procedure that works well. [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/137GAuAjtUD2FcrD1S2IE1DBbvYGusRoyo5WhMMuRGAw/edit?usp=sharing) @Zwenn

Comment: I came across this code and I tried a similar method but it  gives an error "expected: expression"
`document.getElementById('marks-' + '' + at + '-' + i).value`

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have time today. I think tomorrow I will find time to name a few things that I noticed in your VBA code. First of all, I have a question ... Does `FireEvent` work in your macro? It no longer works on most pages. Another question. Do you plan to do more web scraping in the future or is it "only" about this project?

Comment: The `FireEvent` is working for me.

There is no mistake in the code. It was my overlook. I did not change the roll nos of the students in the sheet. Once I changed that it is working as intended.

I am not sure if I need t use web scraping in the future. Thank you for your time and effort.